# ElasticSearch _knn_search query on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, knn, elk

I'm using ES 8.2. I'd like to use approximate method of `_knn_search` on more than 1 vector. Below I've attached my current code searching on a single vector. So far as I've read `_knn_search` does not support search on `nested` fields.
Alternatively, I can use multi index search. One index, one vector, one search, sum up all results together. However, I need to store all these vectors together in one index as I need also to perform filtration on some other fields besides vectors for knn search.

Thus, the question is if there is a work around how I can perform `_knn_search` on more than 1 vector?

```
search_vector = np.zeros(512).tolist()
es_query = {
        "knn": {
            "field": "feature_vector_1.vector",
            "query_vector": search_vector,
            "k": 100,
            "num_candidates": 1000
        },
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "feature_vector_1.match_prc": {
                        "gt": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    "_source": {
        "excludes": ["feature_vector_1.vector", "feature_vector_2.vector"]
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The last working query that I've end up with is

```
es_query = {
            "knn": {
                "field": "feature_vector_1.vector",
                "query_vector": search_vector,
                "k": 1000,
                "num_candidates": 1000
            },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        },
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": {
                                "source": """
                                                  double value = dotProduct(params.queryVector, 'feature_vector_2.vector');
                                                  return 100 * (1 + value) / 2;
                                                """,
                                "params": {
                                    "queryVector": search_vector
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        "_source": {
            "excludes": ["feature_vector_1.vector", "feature_vector_2.vector"]
          }
        }
```

However, it is not true AKNN on 2 vectors but still working option if performance of such query satisfies your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

the below seems to be working for me for combining KNN searches, taking the average of multiple cosine similarity scores. Note that this is a little different than the original request, since it performs a brute force search, but you can still filter the results up front by replacing the `match_all` bit.

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "(cosineSimilarity(params.vector1, 'my-vector1') + cosineSimilarity(params.vector2, 'my-vector2'))/2 + 1.0",
        "params": {
          "vector1": [
            1.3012068271636963,
            ...
            0.23468133807182312
          ],
          "vector2": [
            -0.49404603242874146,
            ...
            -0.15835021436214447
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```